# ASP.NET Core form post to controller is empty if more than 100 items

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a page with a form on it, in which there are a number of checkboxes based on the amount of files in an object. When the form is posted the selected files are put into a list, which I then read in my controller to start the download of the selection.

This works perfectly until I get more than 100 files, then the list is empty, together with the two other parameters.

Here's the page:

```
    <form asp-controller="Product" asp-action="DownloadProductVersionReleaseModuleVersionRelease" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="Download">
       <input type="hidden" name="productVersionReleaseId" id="productVersionReleaseId" value="@Model.ProductVersionRelease.ProductVersionReleaseId"/>
       <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked name="releaseNotes" id="releaseNotes">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <i class="fa fa-sticky-note" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Include releasenotes                  
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul style="list-style-type:none; margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px;">
                foreach (var moduleVersionReleaseFile in productVersionReleaseModuleVersionRelease.ModuleVersionRelease.ModuleVersionReleaseFile)
                {                           
                 <li>
                    <input class="form-check-input ModuleVersionReleaseFile" type="checkbox" id="ModuleVersionReleaseFileId" name="ModuleVersionReleaseFileId" value="@moduleVersionReleaseFile.ModuleVersionReleaseFileId" checked>
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-fw"></i>
                          @moduleVersionReleaseFile.File
                    </label>                                
                 </li>
                           
                        }
            </ul>    
            }
     </form>
```

The method in the controller handling the post:

```
 public async Task DownloadProductVersionReleaseModuleVersionRelease(int productVersionReleaseId, List<int> moduleVersionReleaseFileId, string releaseNotes)
        {
            //basically what happens in here is irrelevant
        }
```

I have tried disabling the request size limit with

```
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
```

Also tried making the requestformlimit higher

```
[DisableRequestSizeLimit,
    RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue,
    ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
```

Setting the request size limit to 100_000_000 also doesn't work:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
```

I have tried adding the following to web.config:

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
   </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Added this to appsettings.json:

```
  "bodyParser": {
      "json": {
          "limit": "50mb",
          "extended": true
      },
      "urlencoded": {
           "limit": "50mb",
           "extended": true
            }
}
```

Comment: I use this in startup: services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue);  But you may not want to use MaxValue as I think it leaves your vulnerable to a certain exploit.  (I'm on a small intranet here...)  Though if the limit were the problem you should be seeing "Bad Request" error methinks...

Comment: I found the issue, there was a checkbox with no value attached to it, which caused this issue. Very strange the list is empty when posting tho.